# Need to extract only the one row using join query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to extract one record from joining the Table X and Table Y.

Below is the query am using

```
SELECT  (select ACCOUNTSALESFORCEDETAILID
        FROM    sysdba.ACCOUNTSALESFORCEDETAIL AS a1
        WHERE   ORGSALESFORCEID = 'QWKHAA000STK' 
        AND     ACCOUNTID = O.ACCOUNTID
        and     MODIFYDATE =    (
                                SELECT  MIN(MODIFYDATE) AS MODIFYDATE
                                FROM    sysdba.ACCOUNTSALESFORCEDETAIL
                                WHERE   ACCOUNTID = a1.ACCOUNTID
                                AND     ORGSALESFORCEID = a1.ORGSALESFORCEID
                                GROUP   BY ACCOUNTID, ORGSALESFORCEID
                                )
        ),
        a.ORGSALESFORCEID
FROM    sysdba.ACCOUNTSALESFORCEDETAIL a  
JOIN    sysdba.ACCOUNT O on a.ACCOUNTID=O.ACCOUNTID 
WHERE   O.ACCOUNTID ='A61E6C43EE71' 
AND     A.ORGSALESFORCEID in ('QWKHAA000STK','QWKHAA01KXNC','QWKHAA01KXNE')
```

Below s the result am getting now:

```
ACCOUNTSALESFORCEID       ORGSALESFORCEID
QB46AC89800B              QWKHAA000STK
QB46AC89800B              QWKHAA01KXNC
QB46AC89800B              QWKHAA01KXNE
```

But i need only First row as the output..

Please help.

Comment: what is your criteria?. What makes first row special from rest?

Comment: Because i have mentioned the Orgsalesforceid='QWKHAA000STK' in the subquery

Comment: you have mentioned like this ` A.ORGSALESFORCEID in ('QWKHAA000STK','QWKHAA01KXNC','QWKHAA01KXNE')` so you are getting 3 rows

Comment: does `select  top(1) ...` will help you??

Comment: @siva i removed that and tried that too.. it didnt work...

Comment: @Nithesh i tried that even.... same result.

Comment: Can you tell what are you trying to get from these tables.Asking just because Same tables are used again and again..

Comment: Please indent your query, so that it will be easy to understand.

Comment: For a particular Accountid there will be three rows (three orgsalesforceid) on Accountsalesforcedetail table. Am trying to extract the the record from Accountsalesforcedetail table based on the Orgsalesforceid i mentioned in subquery. Here i mentioned QWKHAA000STK in sub query so i need that row alone, like wise if i mention other two orgsalesforceid i need to get each record respective to it orgsalesforceid

Comment: have a try with my updated answer.

Comment: @nithesh Thanks!! its throwing error like no column name specified

Comment: try now by giving a column name for the sub-query .. I have updated my answer again.

Comment: @nithesh it works now... But if have to fetch the row with orgsalesforceid QWKHAA01KXNE it doesnot provide me the correct answer...

Comment: add this at end `where ORGSALESFORCEID='QWKHAA01KXNE'`

Answer (score 0):

Have a try like this

```
SELECT TOP(1) col1,ORGSALESFORCEID
FROM
(SELECT
   (
    SELECT    
        ACCOUNTSALESFORCEDETAILID
    FROM    
        sysdba.ACCOUNTSALESFORCEDETAIL AS a1
    WHERE  (ORGSALESFORCEID = 'QWKHAA000STK') 
        AND  (ACCOUNTID=O.ACCOUNTID) 
        AND (MODIFYDATE =(  SELECT     MIN(MODIFYDATE) AS MODIFYDATE
                            FROM     sysdba.ACCOUNTSALESFORCEDETAIL
                            WHERE      (ACCOUNTID = a1.ACCOUNTID) AND (ORGSALESFORCEID=a1.ORGSALESFORCEID)
                            GROUP BY ACCOUNTID, ORGSALESFORCEID)
            )
    ) AS col1
    ,a.ORGSALESFORCEID

FROM 
    sysdba.ACCOUNTSALESFORCEDETAIL a  JOIN sysdba.ACCOUNT O on a.ACCOUNTID=O.ACCOUNTID 
WHERE O.ACCOUNTID='A61E6C43EE71' and   A.ORGSALESFORCEID in ('QWKHAA000STK','QWKHAA01KXNC','QWKHAA01KXNE')
) AS temp
```